# Change category of torrent using qBittorrent web API how?

Tags: bash, webapi, bittorrent

I have a script to add torrents automatically by a bash script where the important command looks like this:
`curl -s -X POST --form "category=$CATEGORY" --form "tags=$TAG" --form root_folder=false --form "torrents=@$SAFENAME" $SERVER/api/v2/torrents/add -s -o /dev/null`

I want to adjust this to be able to [change the category of the added torrents](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-(qBittorrent-4.1)#get-torrent-list) individually, but I can not figure out how to formulate the command to make it happen.

Can anyone help me please. I would really appreciate it.

I can not figure this out myself unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!
This is the command that worked for me, in case someone will read this in the future.
`curl -s -X POST --data "hashes=$HASH&category=$CATEGORY" $SERVER/api/v2/torrents/setCategory -s -o /dev/null`
And the category needs to be urlencoded in case it contains any special characters.